# Asp.net Core iis Error 401.2 - Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-7.5

I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x) article to create a web.api site on my IIS. But I am getting Error 401.2 - Unauthorized. The site has anonymous access enabled, so I not sure where else should I look. Running dotnet command from the command prompt using my dll as a parameter works fine.

Comment: are you using first time iis ??

Answer (score -4):

After messing around with the configuration I was able to get it to work.
I had to put an specifc user in the anonymous access.

Comment: Do you have an example of this?

Comment: Nope.Its a very specific iis configuration.